# How to delete gridview item from SD card onLongClick?

Tags: image, memory, directory

I've seen all the other posts about how to delete an image from the SD card.
I know this has been asked before, and i've implemented all the suggestions people gave, however I keep getting no result.
All the images stay in my sd card directory. 
So I hope someone can find what I'm doing wrong because I'm at a total lost here..

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cookbook);

    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);
    gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(CookbookActivity.this, "You've removed an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Removes the image from the gridview
            myImageAdapter.remove(position);

            // Updates the gridview
            myImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            int i = 0;
            i++;
            // Trying to delete the LongClicked Image from the SD card
            String myFile = "/Food Inspiration/" + "pic-" + i + ".png";

            String myPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+myFile;

            File f = new File(myPath);
            Boolean deleted = f.delete();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**
I found out that it's because of the filepath to my image.
I have a do while loop for making the imagename increment.
So Image1, Image2 and so on.

**The code**

```
int i = 0;
            do {
                sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "pic-" + i + ".png");
                i++;
            } while (sdImageMainDirectory.exists());
```

**UPDATE 2.0**
Alright so I've managed to delete every item at once with this loop:

```
// Deletes EVERY image when LongClicked... cant make it delete 1 image
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                    // Trying to delete the LongClicked Image from the SD card
                    String myFile = "/Food Inspiration/" + "pic-" + i + ".png";

                    String myPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+myFile;

                    File f = new File(myPath);
                    Boolean deleted = f.delete();

                }
```

Does anyone know how I can save just 1 item that I longclick instead of every item at once. I know that i delete everything because of the i < 100 but this is just for testing purposes. I hope someone has an answer how to delete 1 Item at a time.